# UI is not updating automatically while removing element using SignalR in Blazor Server App

Tags: .net, blazor, signalr

I'm building a web app in Blazor Server, which must communicate with my SQL Server Database. I want it to update data automatically whenever some user changes data in the app. I wrote this code and I've got a strange situation. The UI as well as DB update without any problems after adding new client, but when I remove one, it is deleted from the DB, but the UI doesn't update. I have to refresh the page to see changes. What may be the cause of this issue?

```
@code {
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;

    private List<ClientModel> clients = new List<ClientModel>();


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        LoadData();

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/clientsHub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<ClientModel>("DeleteClientUI", client =>
        {
            clients.Remove(client);
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

        });

        hubConnection.On<ClientModel>("CopyClientUI", client =>
        {
            clients.Add(client);
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task DeleteClient(ClientModel client)
    {
        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("RemoveClient", client);
    }

    private async Task CopyClient(ClientModel client)
    {
        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("CopyClient", client);
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("test_db");

            await
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "select * from clients";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            clients.Add(new ClientModel()
                                {
                                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                    Name = reader.GetString(1),
                                    Email = reader.GetString(2),
                                    Phone = reader.GetString(3),
                                    Address = reader.GetString(4),
                                    CreatedOn = reader.GetDateTime(5),
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Hubs
{
    public class ClientsHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public ClientsHub(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task RemoveClient(ClientModel client)
        {
            int id = client.Id;
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("test_db");
            string query = "delete from clients where id=@id";
            await
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("DeleteClientUI", client);
            
        }

        public async Task CopyClient(ClientModel client)
        {
            int id = client.Id;
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("test_db");
            string query = "insert into clients (name, email, phone, address, created_at) select b.name, b.email, b.phone, b.address, b.created_at from clients b where b.id = @id";
            await
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("CopyClientUI", client);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the `clients.Remove(client);` line is working? It doesn't throw an error if it fails, it just returns `false` I believe. I suspect that there is some hash difference between the `client` that is in the collection and the `client` that is being sent via SignalR. Since they are not an exact match it's not actually removing it from the collection. When you refresh it is reloading the collection and so, of course, at that point it's gone since it's no longer in the database. I recommend you override `Equals` on your `ClientModel` to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm interested - why did you choose to use SignalR for this server side code?

Comment: @justyna - avoid `async void`. Make LoadData an `async  Task` method and await it. But that does not look like the core problem here.

Comment: @MisterMagoo. This code is just a prototype. My goal is to create app, that will get data from SQL Server and I need all users to see changes in the database immediately, so I assumed I can use SignalR to have a real-time application.

Comment: I have already fixed that issue. I needed to have more specific point at the client I want to remove.
hubConnection.On<ClientModel>("DeleteClientUI", client =>
  {
   var clientToRemove = clients.Single(item => item.Id == client.Id);
   clients.Remove(clientToRemove);
   InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
  });

Comment: Blazor Server already uses SignalR to communicate with the clients - what you have here is Blazor Server communicating with itself (well, the same host) over another SignalR connection, which is kind of odd.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Well, thanks! I need to learn a lot and read a lot.

Comment: If you're implementing a push to clients to avoid polling SignalR isn't a bad choice, but be aware that everything will work locally and then there is a bug that will prevent it from working in production: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25000. The issue has been open for almost 3 years so it seems that it's not high on the priority list for fixing. Another option is to use a Singleton class that raises events to which all of your clients subscribe.